# In a Feeds architecture(like Facebook news or Twitter), how to make the feeds counts consistent with the feeds lists' length?

Tags: facebook, twitter, redis, hbase, feed

I am designing a Feeds system, that one can post news, and others can see each other's news, just like the Twitter.

Now I'm saving the news in HBase, and cache them in Redis. This approach has O(1) insert, update and remove, but the "count" is something hard to achieve:

If I save a separate count in Redis, and increasing/decreasing it upon insertion/removal, the value can be easily not consistent with the real list length in Hbase: one single failure on the network or some other exception can make the value wronged.

If I get the count from Hbase, it's very time consuming.

What design choice should I make?

Answer (score 0):

HBase provides support for atomic counters: instead of maintaining the count in Redis and relying on multiple system you just can use HBase for everything (in real-time).

Just insert the post, and if everything went ok, increment the counter. You can even have multiple counters to track total posts + posts per day, week, month, year... it's a very powerful feature.

For more info the [HBase Book](https://books.google.es/books?id=Ytbs4fLHDakC&lpg=PA168&ots=b0Rm5OUV6D&dq=hbase%20counters&hl=es&pg=PA168#v=onepage&q=hbase%20counters&f=false) has a few pages dedicated to counters, also, you can check an [increment example](https://github.com/larsgeorge/hbase-book/blob/master/ch04/src/main/java/client/IncrementSingleExample.java).

Comment: Thx! Will definitely look into the HBase counter!

Answer (score 0):

If you choose to go with Redis, I suggest using one of its data structures. You can store the feed in a list, or sorted set, and those can return their length in O(1) or O(log(N)). And if you can't afford to make the query O(log(N)), you can atomically cache the notification count every time you insert in the sorted set.